# Textarea's CSS Box-Shadow not working on IE11

Tags: css, internet-explorer, textarea, internet-explorer-11, box-shadow

I can't make `box-shadow` property to work correctly on `textarea` element in Internet Explorer 11. I've already found some solutions like adding `border-collapse: separate;`, but they don't seem to work for me. 
[image]

This is the CSS code of the element.

```
.bootstrap-frm input[type="text"], .bootstrap-frm input[type="email"], .bootstrap-frm textarea, .bootstrap-frm select{
    border: 0px solid #CCC;
    background-color: #d3d3d3;
    color: #888;
    height: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 16px;
    margin-right: 6px;
    outline: 0 none;
    padding: 5px 0px 5px 5px;
    width: 55%;
    border-radius: 4px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
    -moz-border-radius: 4px;
    box-shadow: inset 0 2px 4px rgba(136, 136, 136, 1);
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 2px 4px rgba(136, 136, 136, 1);
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 2px 4px rgba(136, 136, 136, 1);
}

.bootstrap-frm textarea{
    height: 205px;
    width: 95%;
}
```

Rest of code is not important - only inherited parameters are `text-align`, `font-size` and `font-family`. Thanks for any help.

Comment: Your vendor prefix ordering is all wrong.  Vendor prefixes go before the un-prefixed attribute as the last-appearing rule will override the rest. Not likely to solve your problem, but will probably save _you_ some cross-browser issues down the line and _me_ the wincing I experienced looking this over the first time.

Comment: Same here. Adding `overflow:auto` seems to be good, until the content overflows and makes the scrollbar appear: it becomes buggy again.

Comment: Have you found a better solution yet?

Comment: Not perfect, but useful: `border: 1px solid transparent;` indtead of `border: 0px solid #CCC;`.